# Can I play lands from the graveyard more than once in a turn with Crucible of Worlds?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I have [Crucible of Worlds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrucible%20of%20Worlds%5d) out and I summon then sacrifice an [Evolving Wilds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEvolving%20Wilds%5d) from my graveyard. Can I then replay Evolving Wilds from my graveyard that turn or will it have counted as playing my one land for the turn?

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the Gatherer page for the Crucible, it tells you that

> Crucible of Worlds doesn’t change the times when you can play those land cards. You can still play **only one land per turn**, and only during your main phase when you have priority and the stack is empty.

(Emphasis mine.) So the lands played from the graveyard do not get a separate land-playing quota.

Answer (score 5):

**No, you cannot play the Evolving Wilds for a second time in that turn.**

The ability on Crucible of Worlds says

> You may play land cards from your graveyard.

Playing land card this way is the same exact action as playing land card from your hand normally. So the same restrictions apply and you can only take that action once per turn. Once you play the Evolving Wilds from the graveyard, you can't play the same card from the graveyard again that turn, and you can't play another land from your hand that turn.

Comment: Thank you for that I appreciate it. Made my game take longer thinking about it lol

Answer (score 3):

If you played Evolving Wilds on that same turn; that counts as your land play for the turn, and Crucible of Worlds doesn't allow you to play an extra land.

However, the land you get from activating Evolving Wilds does not count as playing a land; Evolving Wilds has you "put a land onto the battlefield". That is not the same as "play a land".

Answer (score 2):

You are still restricted by the one land per turn rule, it doesn't matter where that land is played from (note put into play is different, such as effects like [Rampant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRampant%20Growth%5d))

This can be modified by cards that allow more land plays, [Fastbond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFastbond%5d), [Zuran Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZuran%20Orb%5d) and Crucible were a combo at one time to allow infinite replaying of lands that had effects when you played or sacrificed them (a combo that would probably have added [Field of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bField%20of%20the%20Dead%5d) to it)

Short answer, you still only get one land play a turn, from hand or from graveyard, unless you have something that changes that like Fastbond, [Explore](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394363) or [Rites of Flourishing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRites%20of%20Flourishing%5d). All Crucible does is change where 305.1 lets you play land from.

> **[305.1](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Land)** A player who has priority may play a land card from their hand during a main phase of their turn when the stack is empty. Playing a land is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 116). Rather, the player simply puts the land onto the battlefield. Since the land doesn’t go on the stack, it is never a spell, and players can’t respond to it with instants or activated abilities.